# How runtime permissions are handled in Android instant app?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Android N Developer preview introduced a new feature called [Android Instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html?utm_campaign=io16&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog).

I read basic information about this topic and here is my understanding:

Android Instant Apps enables Android apps to run instantly, without requiring full scale app installation. that means suppose user discovered an app from search, social media, messaging or other deep links, they can directly access `Activity` belonging to this App,and use functionality within the app, without going to `Google Play store`, clicking Install App etc. thus bypassing app installation flow.

But then, suppose the `Activity` which is getting installed through Instant apps requires a Dangerous permission to work, when it will be invoked?

Basically, how android runtime permissions are to be handled in Android instant apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Instant Apps FAQ](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html):

> **How do permissions work in Android Instant Apps?**
>
> Android Instant Apps uses the [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) model introduced in Android 6.0. If an app supports the permission model introduced in Android 6.0 (API level 23), it does not require any additional work to become an Instant App that runs on older devices.

No matter what device an Instant App is used on, it will always use the runtime permissions model.

Comment: that is not technically correct, as IA can be used on a device all the way to API 22 if I'm not mistaken, which is still Android Lollipop, which didn't have runtime permissions. In that case the dangerous permissions will be granted automatically at install time as long as they are mentioned in the manifest, but you won't see any runtime popup, even if the application code for it is there

Comment: @EmilianCebuc - that's true for installed apps, but **Instant Apps** is something entirely different and they do use runtime permissions even on older versions of Android.